# Android asynchronous Task finishes before Firebasequery completed

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database, android-service

I want to execute some Firebasequery in an asynchronous Task. The Problem is that i have to call Thread.sleep(5000); to get the expected resultlist. Otherwise the List is always empty because the Task ends without waiting for completion of the Firebasequery. 
The task is called from a backgroundservice and waits for the result via Task.execute().get();

Are there any possibilities to get the asynch Tasks result without calling Thread.sleep()?

```
     @Override
protected ArrayList<Product> doInBackground(InventoryCheckService... params) {
    this.service = params[0];
    result = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference userReference = DatabaseAdapter.getInstance().getUserReference();
    if(userReference != null){
        userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                HashMap<String, Product> changedProducts = dataSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Product>>() {
                });
                if(changedProducts != null){
                    Iterator<String> iterator = changedProducts.keySet().iterator();
                    String nextExpirationDate = getDateForTommorow();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String nextKey = iterator.next();
                        Product product = changedProducts.get(nextKey);
                        if (product.getBestBeforeDate().containsKey(nextExpirationDate)) {
                            result.add(product);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help! :)

Comment: Why are you executing Firebasequery in Async Task, i guess all firebase queries executes asynchronously.

Comment: @KamranAhmedKhan, this Tasks is invoked by a backgroundservice. It's a scheduled backgroundservice (I'm using Firebase.Jobdispatcher, which extends Service). As I understood the UI-Thread is blocked while executing a Service, long operations so I moved the logic to a Task....
[Android IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my Issue. I wanted to raise an Intent after Taskexecution. Instead of starting the Intent from the Service, I used to put the Code into the asynchronous Task:

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap<String, Product> changedProducts = dataSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Product>>() {
            });
            if(changedProducts != null){
                Iterator<String> iterator = changedProducts.keySet().iterator();
                String nextExpirationDate = getDateForTommorow();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String nextKey = iterator.next();
                    Product product = changedProducts.get(nextKey);
                    if (product.getBestBeforeDate().containsKey(nextExpirationDate)) {
                        result.add(product);
                    }
                }
                 // start Intent here...
            }
```

Now I dont have to sleep until the Task is completed, because it is part of the Task to start the Intent.